# Filtering 2 sample source in dashboard (FocusVision Decipher)

Tags: xml

Im trying to create a 2 separate dashboard in decipher. I do have 2 sample sources and each of them needs different dashboard. I already created one for them as whole where any data coming from them regardless of sample source will fall under on that dashboard. My main concern is how can I filter each sample source in dashboard using xml in able to collect data from each. Thanks and regards!

```
page Profile

table id=db-16
uses TableResponse
tableresponse.columns "record, sample source.gmor"


table id=db-1 Total
total
rows status.qualified
rows status.terminated

table id=db-14 width=6 Area - Region/City
filter.local id=db-15 qualified
total
    row s6.ch1 National Capital Region (NCR)
    row s6.ch2 North/Central Luzon
    row s6.ch3 South Luzon/Bicol
    row s6.ch4 Visayas
    row s6.ch5 Mindanao
    banner.local
    segment s4.ch1 Male
    segment s4.ch2 Female


table id=db-9 width=4 Age
filter.local id=db-10 qualified
total 
    row s5.ch2 20-30 y.o
    row s5.ch3 31-40 y.o
    row s5.ch4 41-50 y.o

table id=db-6 width=4 Gender
filter.local id=db-11 qualified
total
    row s4.ch1 Male
    row s4.ch2 Female
```